# Is pandas to_sql() method allows us to specify database name

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I created a sqlalchemy engine using the db as `default_db`

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@hostname/default_db')
```

When I try to insert a record into a table `test` which is in db `new_db` using pandas `to_sql()`, It doesn't take the table **`name`** that specified with database.

```
result = dataFrame.to_sql(f"{new_db}.{test}", engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

`result` returned here is `None`.

Is there any way to specify different db in `to_sql()` method while engine created with some other db?

Comment: *It doesn't take the table name that specified with database.* ... Don't leave us in suspense, what name did it take instead? And `to_sql` being an action call (like `to_csv`, `to_json`, `to_xml`) usually will return `None`.

Comment: to_sql() has a schema parameter, which is an alias to databae in mysql. You could try using that.

Comment: I'd really like to know the answer to this. In my case I'm connecting to MS SQL Server with a connection string like `mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=hostname;DATABSE=TheDB;UID=xyz;PWD=XYZ;`. When I call `pd.to_sql("TheDB.table", con=connection, if_exists="append")` I get "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'" even though the table does exist and I'm specifying the database.